# problem with converting into pdf file

Tags: lyx, pdf

I face the problem of converting my file into PDF. Everything was working fine until today.  I reinstalled my LYX to 2.1.3. And now when I want to convert to PDF , it does not see my graphs inserted as `.emf` files.

How to fix this problem ? it says : 'An error occurred while running epsdpdf -outfile .....'. What can it mean?

Comment: LaTeX does not accept .emf. LyX tries to help you out by first converting them to a format that LaTeX does accept before calling LaTeX, but apparently the conversion went bad. Try converting your .emf files to .pdf or .eps and reinsert them and try again. As for why it worked before, well the conversion worked before for whatever reason. I don't know how it works on Windows, but I think it might use ghostscript to do the conversion.

Comment: Hi scottkosty, for me it was convenient to use .emf files, because LYx created them automatically, and cut also in a good format. While for pdf or eps i should prescribe myself (isn't it ???)  but as it turned out new version doe snot want to accpet my older LYX 2.1.1.  do anyone knows why it does not want to work now (this new version "2.1.3)??

Comment: Just to make sure that that is the only problem, can you try converting them manually? As for what is going wrong, I am not sure. If you were on Ubuntu I would suggest you start LyX from the terminal with `lyx -dbg graphics`. I don't know if that is easy on Windows.