# Problem with new version LyX 2.1.3

Tags: graphics, lyx

I tried to open an older file with inserted  figures in `.emf` files (actually created automatically by LyX when inserting copied pictures). I wonder why new LyX 2.1.3 allows inserting but does not see them in the file and does not want subsequently to compile them into pdf.

I can convert these `.emf` files into pdf files, but for me `.emf` files were more convenient since where formatted automatically by LyX (width and height, etc.).

Is it possible somehow to solve this problem without changing `.emf` files?

Comment: Seems your Lyx installation is screwed. Which OS are you using? If Windows, uninstall Lyx and install again. Don't try to overwrite an existing installation with a newer version.

Comment: Hi , yes, i reinstalled it from the beginning. Are you sure  new version should read .emf files??? seems it is ok with pdf.

Comment: @Kate it is useful when you create questions that are related that you reference the other questions. This question for example is related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256204/problem-with-converting-into-pdf-file